# How to make SFZ file from wv using only open source software?

Tags: audiokit

I have read these instructions:
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/v4.2/Documentation/PreparingSampleSets.md

But have not got Logic or Mainstage.

Is it possible to create a SFZ file for use in ROM Player without using commercial software?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put and SFZ together using [sforzando](https://www.plogue.com/products/sforzando.html).